# Click Button to load Google Maps on other page (jquery mobile/javascript)

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, cordova

So I am trying to make a mobile app with lake pages. I want to be able to click on a button link and be brought to a page that has the map on it.
This is all done in Jquery mobile and I don't want external pages. (so like "#map-page")

I have go the code I want working in general. But as far as making it initiate on a click event I have had no luck. I have been through multiple examples and such.
I want the map to load when I'm on the page so the mobile app doest need to load a shit ton of maps.

I have made an example on jsFiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/Ajfvr/

So instead of it loading with the onload property I need it to load on another nested page (fullscreen) once you click the link to the page. So the js doesn't get initiate until they click the link.

please help <3 thanks.

The Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>    
  <head> 
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../jquery/jquery-1.4.4.min.js"></script>        
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?v=3&sensor=false&language=en"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../cordova-2.3.0.js"></script>
        <style>
      html, body, #map_canvas {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        height: 100%;
      }
    </style>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function detectBrowser() {
    var useragent = navigator.userAgent;
    var mapdivMap = document.getElementById("map_canvas");

    if (useragent.indexOf('iPhone') != -1 || useragent.indexOf('Android') != -1 ) {
        mapdivMap.style.width = '100%';
        mapdivMap.style.height = '100%';
        initialize();
    } else {
        mapdivMap.style.width = '600px';
        mapdivMap.style.height = '800px';
        initialize();
        }
    };

    function initialize() {
        var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 8,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(43.464258,-80.52041),
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'),
            mapOptions);

        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: map.getCenter(),
            map: map,
            title: 'Waterloo'
        });
    }

      google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', detectBrowser);
    </script> 
  </head>
  <body onload="detectBrowser()">
    <div id="map_canvas"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I understand from your question is that you want to load the map in an entirely new page. Or if you want to load the map on the same page, and yet delay the loading of the map, you could simply call the function on click of a button and load the map in an overlay DIV using Javascript.

jQuery Mobile has a way to prefetch (load in advance) pages. You could look into that too, if you are trying to load the maps in advance.

Comment: Yah so I want this javascript to execute only when a button that says "View map" is clicked. Then another nested page is then transitioned too and it loads the map. I want to do this so it doesn't load all these maps and it only loads when the user wants to see them specifically.

Comment: Well, instead of an onload, you could call the function like this:

Use <input type="submit" onclick="yourfunction()"/> You could hide/show an overlay like [THIS](http://www.emanueleferonato.com/downloads/lightbox.html) and call the maps function along with the show overlay. This will delay loading the maps till the button is clicked.

Comment: Alright so I want to thank you Gautam for pointing me in the right direction!

Comment: With that information. I have used an overlay div to pop up when a buttton in clicked. Once clicked I made sure it would launch the code for the map. I played around for it to work well in android only tested on 2.3.3 in emulator but its working pretty well. The close button wouldn't show even changing the z-index didn't work. I tried a cutsom one but that didnt work so I ended up taking the code from google maps api v3 for custom controls and making a close button. I have struggled endlessly because of certain things I needed. This example will help you if you are stuck as well.

Comment: Here is the code on jsFiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/bQcBt/           The variables and some stuff have not been changed atm because I just want it to work. So with this code. I am able to have Google maps in my mobile app without it loading when the app is launched (saving memory) and also no longer need a nested page for it to go too. If you are coding a Mobile app with Jquery on Cordova (or phonegap, same thing) I can help answer some of your questions if I have run into them! Steam: 99cptsnow  Email: CptSnowReveille@hotmail.com

Comment: Nice work, I'm sure that would be of great help to someone having struggling with the same problem.

Comment: IF you have multiple maps and want to have the close button more than once refer to my other question for a solution on multiple toggle control buttons : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14886917/add-multiple-custom-control-buttons-on-google-maps-api-v3