# Add Multiple Custom Control buttons on Google Maps API v3

Tags: javascript, api, google-maps, button, controls

I have 2 Google maps on the same page and I am looking to add the same button to a map that already has one.
This button is to close the overlay that Google maps launches in, basically an exit button.

The Button works fine on the first map but I cant get the second one to work D:!
I know I have to change the variables because that's what I had to do to get 2 maps on one page. Also if someone else is good in Google Maps API v3 can you tell me why I need the "map" variable in the `function HomeControl(controlDiv, map) {` line?
Here is my code:

```
function HomeControl(controlDiv, map) {

      // Set CSS styles for the DIV containing the control
      // Setting padding to 5 px will offset the control
      // from the edge of the map.
      controlDiv.style.padding = '5px';

      // Set CSS for the control border.
      var controlUI = document.createElement('div');
      controlUI.style.backgroundColor = 'white';
      controlUI.style.borderStyle = 'solid';
      controlUI.style.borderWidth = '2px';
      controlUI.style.cursor = 'pointer';
      controlUI.style.textAlign = 'center';
      controlUI.title = 'Click to set the map to Home';
      controlDiv.appendChild(controlUI);

      // Set CSS for the control interior.
      var controlText = document.createElement('div');
      controlText.style.fontFamily = 'Arial,sans-serif';
      controlText.style.fontSize = '12px';
      controlText.style.paddingLeft = '4px';
      controlText.style.paddingRight = '4px';
      controlText.innerHTML = '<strong>Home</strong>';
      controlUI.appendChild(controlText);

      // Setup the click event listeners: simply set the map to Chicago.
      google.maps.event.addDomListener(controlUI, 'click', function() {
        document.getElementById('light').style.display='none';
        document.getElementById('fade').style.display='none';
      });
    }

        function detectBrowser() {
        var useragent = navigator.userAgent;
        var mapdivMap = document.getElementById("light");

        if (useragent.indexOf('iPhone') != -1 || useragent.indexOf('Android') != -1 ) {
            mapdivMap.style.width = '100%';
            mapdivMap.style.height = '100%';
            initialize();
        } else {
            mapdivMap.style.width = '600px';
            mapdivMap.style.height = '100%';
            initialize();
            }
        };

        function initialize() {
            var mapOptions = {
            zoom: 8,
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(43.464258,-80.52041),
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            };
            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('light'),
                mapOptions);

            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: map.getCenter(),
                map: map,
                title: 'Waterloo'
            });


      // Create the DIV to hold the control and call the HomeControl() constructor
      // passing in this DIV.
      var homeControlDiv = document.createElement('div');
      var homeControl = new HomeControl(homeControlDiv, map);

      homeControlDiv.index = 1;
      map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_RIGHT].push(homeControlDiv);

        }



        //*******************************************************
        //************ Conestoga Map Page JavaScript ************ 
        //*******************************************************

        function Map2(Map2Div, map2) {

      // Set CSS styles for the DIV containing the control
      // Setting padding to 5 px will offset the control
      // from the edge of the map.
      Map2Div.style.padding = '5px';

      // Set CSS for the control border.
      var Map2UI = document.createElement('div');
      Map2UI.style.backgroundColor = 'white';
      Map2UI.style.borderStyle = 'solid';
      Map2UI.style.borderWidth = '2px';
      Map2lUI.style.cursor = 'pointer';
      Map2UI.style.textAlign = 'center';
      Map2UI.title = 'Click to set the map to Home';
      Map2Div.appendChild(Map2UI);

      // Set CSS for the control interior.
      var Map2Text = document.createElement('div');
      Map2Text.style.fontFamily = 'Arial,sans-serif';
      Map2Text.style.fontSize = '12px';
      Map2Text.style.paddingLeft = '4px';
      Map2Text.style.paddingRight = '4px';
      Map2Text.innerHTML = '<strong>Home</strong>';
      Map2UI.appendChild(Map2Text);

      // Setup the click event listeners: simply set the map to Chicago.
      google.maps.event.addDomListener(MapUI2, 'click', function() {
        document.getElementById('light').style.display='none';
        document.getElementById('fade').style.display='none';
      });
    }


        function detectBrowser2() {
        var useragent2 = navigator.userAgent;
        var mapdivMap2 = document.getElementById("light");

        if (useragent2.indexOf('iPhone') != -1 || useragent2.indexOf('Android') != -1 ) {
            mapdivMap2.style.width = '100%';
            mapdivMap2.style.height = '100%';
            initialize2();
        } else {
            mapdivMap2.style.width = '600px';
            mapdivMap2.style.height = '100%';
            initialize2();
            }
        };

        function initialize2() {
            var mapOptions2 = {
            zoom: 8,
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(43.464258,-80.52041),
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            };
            var map2 = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('light'),
                mapOptions2);

            var marker2 = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: map.getCenter(),
                map: map2,
                title: 'Waterloo'
            });


      // Create the DIV to hold the control and call the HomeControl() constructor
      // passing in this DIV.
       var Map2Div = document.createElement('div');
       var Map2 = new Map2(Map2Div, map2);

      Map2Div.index = 1;
      map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_RIGHT].push(Map2Div);
        }
```

Comment: Alright so after dozens of hours and lots of trial an error I have finally got this to work! When making multiple control buttons you must name the other variables specifically (from what I tested). When you look at my code you will see that only numbers give them a unique difference. Personally I don't know why this is. Also changing the map variable to be unique in each function seemed to break this control button as well. But with the button click calling the function each time (refreshing it) there was no need for unique map variables. Once map was 'global' everything fit together nicely.

Comment: By global I also mean map is map in every `initialize()` function. You can take this and apply it as you will. Change the listener to do what you will on click mine is used to close the map since it is launched at 100% height and width (for mobile support). Just duplicate and change to your liking. If you need support or help with this feel free to email me.    Here is the link to the code:    http://jsfiddle.net/G9VPc/